# Is there a C# refactoring tool that can convert all declarations to fully qualified types?

Tags: c#, .net, types, refactoring

Here's what needs to be done.

Let's imagine you have the following piece of C# code:

```
private Int32 DoSomething(Int32 number, String message) 
{
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
    Regex regex = null;
    // code goes here
}
```

This will need to become:

```
private System.Int32 DoSomething(System.Int32 number, System.String message) 
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = null;

    // code goes here
}
```

I've found tools that do the opposite (e.g. ReSharper), but the types absolutely need to be fully-qualified, not just consistent.

Comment: why do you need this?

Comment: Some creepy code standards, m.b.?

Comment: One way would be to remove all usings then fix the errors, i think in the menu option you get when right-clicking on the type can either add the using statement, or fully qualify the type.

Comment: It is, in fact, for code standards (no epithet necessary). In my personal projects, I typically use usings with non-fully-qualified types, and I mouse over the types to see where they come from ;)

Comment: pff, just ignore the "standard". seriously.

Comment: Ignore the standard? I'm not that suicidal.

Comment: Seriously? Did the person who made that "standard" think of what would happen when using generics?`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.String, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Int32>>`

Comment: The standard is very verbose by design, and I'm not the one defining it...  There's a lot of things in that standard I probably wouldn't use for a small home-brewn app, but conciseness is not one of the stated goals.

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin It's sometimes useful temporarily, when porting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard with Roslyn. You need to get all `TypeSyntax` nodes, then ask the semantic model for the corresponding `ITypeSymbol`, then get the fully qualified name from the symbol and finally replace the `TypeSyntax` node with a new `TypeSyntax` node.

I wrote a quickfix that replaces `var` with the shortest possible concrete type, you might want to use that as an inspiration: https://github.com/CodesInChaos/Roslyn/tree/master/Chaos.VarToConcrete

Since you want to replace all occurances, and the Roslyn-Visual-Studio isn't too stable yet, I'd go for a roslyn console application instead of a code-issue-provider.

Comment: Would Roslyn mess with the rest of the code (whitespace, etc.)?

Comment: If you are careful it keeps the whitespace the same. Whitespace is represented as "Trivia", so when replacing a node be careful to keep it.

Comment: Ouch! Roslyn requires VS 2010 Service Pack 1. The same standard says I need to use RTM.

Oh well... I guess I'll just comment out the usings and keep right-clicking 'til I die. I should have picked up on the coding style used by the author of the standard... rather than assuming that if the standard doesn't explicitly say it must be fully qualified, I can omit the prefix. How stupid of me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Microsoft Roslyn to write your own tool for this task. It allows You to parse source code and do the analysis and  modification. It is in CTP version at the moment but it will do the work. And there is enough documentation for your needs. Sorry for not posting any link, i am writing this from cell phone.

Comment: I found it, don't worry. I have some basic googling skills. I could even google it with Bing ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure such a tool exists.

One way would be to remove all usings then fix the errors. In the menu option you get when right-clicking on the type you can either add the using statement, or fully qualify the type.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating an addin for Visual Studio that instead of changing all references, displays an overlay with the fully-qualified name (not just when the mouse is over a type)? I assume this would require much less effort and would probably add a real value, which this coding-standard really doesn't. Obviously it wasn't your idea, but most people will agree that this will definitly make your code harder to read. Providing your superior with a nice extension which will aid him not only in looking at your company's code but also at others too, might help you out some day.

I could see others wanting such a feature too, but I can't imagine wanting the fully-qualified name for every type to display everywhere.

If you installed the Visual Studio SDK you get an Editor Classifier template which might be a good starting point (haven't really thought about the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about tools, but hey... what about the

Find:
Int32 (and every type you need)

Replace with:
System.Int32 (and etc.)

Not the best solution, but with small project it will take less time than searching the tool )

Comment: No, it's too big for that. And it's not just system types that need to be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

It may not help you, but the IL code generated by the C# compiler does this automatically.

Your code produces the following IL (if you add a line to return something in DoSomething):

```
.method private hidebysig instance int32 
        DoSomething(int32 number,
                    string message) cil managed
{
  // Code size       11 (0xb)
  .maxstack  1
  .locals init ([0] class [mscorlib]System.Text.StringBuilder stringBuilder,
           [1] class [System]System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex,
           [2] int32 CS$1$0000)
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldnull
  IL_0002:  stloc.0
  IL_0003:  ldnull
  IL_0004:  stloc.1
  IL_0005:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0006:  stloc.2
  IL_0007:  br.s       IL_0009
  IL_0009:  ldloc.2
  IL_000a:  ret
} // end of method Program::DoSomething
```